# React dropdown defaultValue for select not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following code, which renders either a dropdown list, or just a name. Clicking on a button calls the `setState` which updates `editingParent` to true. The variable `parent` is a queried variable from the backend.

```
{editingParent ? 
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" defaultValue={parent.name}>
        {ancestors.map((item) => <option key={item._id} value={item._id}>{item.name}</option>
    </select> :
    <>
        <span>{parent.name}</span>
        <span class="material-icons edit-parent" onClick={handleParentClick}>mode_edit</span>
    </>
}
```

However, upon changing from the name to the dropdown upon clicking on the button, the defaultValue of parent.name is not set to the default. I've also tried conditionally rendering a selected on the `option` that matches parent.name but that doesn't work either. For this assignment, I'm not allowed to use react-select. Having a normal dropdown with defaultValue that doesn't conditionally appear seems to work with defaultValue correctly.

How can I get defaultValue working?

Comment: Hi There. Consider adding a minimum reproducible demo. Since your code is working fine and the issue must be with the backend variable. Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-zhukovsky-9gcns?file=/src/App.js. It's working fine.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I can't seem to figure out the issue, but it seems that if I set `defaultValue` to any String that was mapped, it doesn't work. If I set it to a hardcoded String and have a hardcoded `option`, then it works. I will get back to you with a reproducible example after I figure out how to reproduce it on codesandbox.io.

Comment: sure. will wait.

Comment: I can't seem to make a reproducible example, seems like it should work. I make sure that my array has the defaultValue I want to set it to (checked with `includes` and a `===` operator), and I even try to hardcode defaultValue to a value in the dropdown.

I tried to make a reproducible example on codesandbox but it always worked. However, when I pasted the same exact code into mine, it did not work for some reason. I didn't use backend variables in either example yet it seemed to only work on codesandbox.

Comment: @NisanthReddy Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shamir-u1jts?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you have used `value={index}` in the code. Change it to `value={item}` and then `c` is getting filled as default.